# How to enable CONFIG_PREEMPT option in Linux kernel?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel

I am new bee in Linux kernel programming, trying to work with an old kernel Linux 2.6.32 on x86_64. I want to enable the CONFIG_PREEMPT option in it but can not find information about how can I do it. I can compile a new kernel with my preferred options, but do not know what I need to do in this case. So can anyone please tell me

How can I enable CONFIG_PREEMPT option? Do I need to recompile the kernel again with new menuconfig? In that case which option is responsible for CONFIG_PREEMPT?

I think it's trivial for anyone who worked with this before, so please give me your valuable help!

Comment: You really couldn't find information on how to do this [anywhere](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git/tree/Documentation/kbuild/kconfig.txt)?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `make menuconfig` to enable **CONFIG_PREEMPT** for the kernel; just select it from the menu options. To verify that it's enabled, check the `.config` file generated by `make menuconfig` for the following line:

```
CONFIG_PREEMPT=y
```

You can also make the modification by hand if you prefer (`make menuconfig` is simply a GUI to create the `.config` file).

Once everything is configured, recompile the kernel with the usual:

```
make && make modules_install && make install
```

Comment: @TJ974 if you find Vilhelm's answer useful and it solved your problem please consider accepting his answer :)

Comment: @TJ974 If you need any further assistance with this question please let me know. If the answer is satisfactory, "accept" the answer by clicking the checkmark to the left of it under the vote count (the large number to the left of the text).

Comment: To find the whereabouts of that CONFIG_PREEMPT option, type / (slash) in make menuconfig and search for PREEMPT.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add fully optimized kernel, you need to add a patch, which can be downloaded from the main website [here](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/rt/)
If you don't know how to add a patch, just go through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18892376/how-to-add-patch-to-build-real-time-preempted-kernel) thread.

Comment: But, its better if you choose the same version patch.

Answer (score 0):

One can often install a corresponding package, such as the `linux-image-4.19.0-12-rt-amd64-unsigned` on Debian

```
apt install linux-image-4.19.0-12-rt-amd64-unsigned
grep PREEMPT /boot/config-4.19.0-12-rt-amd64
sync && reboot

grep PREEMPT /proc/version
Linux version 4.19.0-12-rt-amd64 (debian-kernel@lists.debian.org) (gcc version 8.3.0 (Debian 8.3.0-6)) #1 SMP PREEMPT RT Debian 4.19.152-1 (2020-10-18)
```